# How to add a asp.net membership provider to asp.net web application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, wcf, web-services

I am trying to figure this one out. I am using a simple web service that is hosted by an asp.net web application that is going to be used for authentication for a mobile client and a desktop client and it will also be used to send/receive information to and from the clients.

Right now the service uses custom username and password authentication that is hard coded into the service. I need some kind of authentication though. So I figured I could just add the asp.net membership provider to the web application that is hosting the service, and I could use that database for the members for the service.

This would provide a way for me to manage the users as well. Could anyone tell me if this would work and if so how could it be implmented?

Here is the service I am using: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/96028/WCF-Service-with-custom-username-password-authenti

Answer (score 0):

It is easy to do. Assuming you're using Visual Studio I suggest using the web site administration tool. A MSDN article describing adding ASP.NET Membership Provider can be found at [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6e9y4s5t(v=vs.100).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6e9y4s5t%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)